# How to pass a value to a child component in react

Tags: json, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have two components, one which calls the other. In this case my component `Entries` has the below line.

```
<TypeIcon typeicon={entry.type} />
```

This line calls the below component `TypeIcon`.

```
import React from 'react';

import '../../App.css'




function TypeIcon (props){

  return (
    <span><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  )
}

export default TypeIcon
```

What I'm attempting to do is to do some conditional rendering on the `type` value (show a doc icon or a play icon) which is switched on the value in `entry`. The JSON below is mapped to `entry`:

```
[{
    "domain": "https://matangitonga.to",
    "publishdate": "2017-09-06",
    "title": "Tonga's general election set for November 16",
    "type": "article",
    "language": "EN",
    "event_id": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "url": "https://matangitonga.to/2017/09/06/tongas-general-election-set-november-16"
}]
```

What I'm having trouble with is the way in which to correctly pass either `entry` or `entry.type` into `TypeIcon`.

Comment: It's not really clear what's not working. Are you assigning the json property value to `entry.type` after it's retrieved?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; you *are* passing it in (assuming you've taken it out of the array via a `map` or explicit array reference).

Comment: I've tried this a couple of ways. Once as entry.type and another time as entry. The crux of the problem is how to assign it to a variable in the child component and then render it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pass the value as

```
<TypeIcon typeicon={entry.type} />
```

then you can access it in children component as

```
{props.typeicon}
```

because all your props are passed through the props object and typeicon is just a key in your props object

if you pass the whole entry object then you can access the icon in your child compoent as.

```
{props.typeicon.type}
```

because the whole entry object become the value for the key typeicon and to access the type property you have to access it one step deeper

Comment: My mistake was in thinking that the variable I was creating as a prop `typeicon={entry.type}` could be referenced differently in the child component `{props.type}`